# How to stop multiple calls on some events in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to check the length of the input from a text area in my page. For this I have done as below:

```
    <textarea id="reviews_comment" name="comment" value="<?php echo $this->input->post('comment'); ?>" ></textarea>
    <button style="display: none;" id="comment_button" class="btn btn-success"  >Add Comment</button>
```

The associated script is as under:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

     $('#reviews_comment').bind('input propertychange', function() {

     var review = $('#reviews_comment').val()
        if(review.length>=4){
           $('#comment_button').show();
           $('#comment_button').on('click',function(){
            alert($('#reviews_comment').val());
           })
        }
      })

     });
    </script>
```

When I do this, on clicking 'Add comment button' I get alert for multiple times if more that 4 letters are input. But if I input just 4 letters then it alerts only one time. Also when I alert review.length it alerts starting from 4 up to the number of letters entered.
What is the real issue here? Any kind of help are highly appreciated. Thanks.

[image: picture]

Comment: Use `console.log()` to view your input value instead of `alert`.

Comment: I did but the results come as the picture above which i just added.

Comment: Don't use `.bind`. It maps directly to `.on` in the current version of jQuery.  So there is a tiny but practically insignificant performance hit if you use `.bind` instead. `.bind` may be removed from future versions at any time. There is no reason to keep using `.bind` and every reason to prefer `.on` instead.

Comment: @SuzAannshrestha If the problem is the number of calls and not the `alert` itself, change your question. It's unclear and at least too broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding a click event for every character you type into the textarea. You should only add one click event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#reviews_comment').bind('input propertychange', function() {

    var review = $('#reviews_comment').val()
    if (review.length >= 4) {
      $('#comment_button').show();

    }
  })
  $('#comment_button').on('click', function() {
    alert($('#reviews_comment').val());
  })
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7uj6xt68/

Comment: Thanks for your support. :)

Comment: @AlivetoDie https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50697/time-limit-on-accepting-an-answer

Answer (score 1):

Move the event binding out:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#reviews_comment').bind('input propertychange', function() {

            var review = $('#reviews_comment').val()
            if (review.length >= 4) {
                $('#comment_button').show();

            }
        });
        $('#comment_button').on('click', function() {
            alert($('#reviews_comment').val());
        });

    });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/2208/

The event is rebinded again everytime user types something in the textarea